# Recharts Event not working when bar chart bar value is 0

Tags: reactjs, recharts

I am using Recharts [BarChart](http://recharts.org/#/en-US/api/BarChart) components to visualize my data. In the [Bar component](http://recharts.org/#/en-US/api/Bar), it supports a few events handler (onClick, onMouseDown, etc).

**My question**: I have an onClick event handler so users are able to click on the bar chart and redirect to other pages based on the result ID.

**My problem**: If the bar chart's value is at 0, users are unable to click on the link since onClick event handler is implemented on the bar itself.

**Source code**:

```
<BarChart
  width={500}
  height={500}
  layout="vertical"
  data={data}
>
  <XAxis type="number" />
  <YAxis dataKey="title" type="category" />
  <Bar
    dataKey="score"
    fill={Color}
    label={<CustomLabel />}
    onClick={(data, index) => {
      // some logic here
      return history.push(`/${data.x.y.id}`);
    }}
  />
</BarChart>
```

**Screenshot**:
[image: Sample Picture]

**My attempt**:

I tried to look at a possible solution and observe the examples on the API in recharts website, I don't see anything that is able to solve my problem. I also tried to have onClick on the title on axis or bar, but the component does not support the feature. Please advise.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add an onClick attribute on the [BarChart](http://recharts.org/#/en-US/api/BarChart) component and check `data.activePayload[0]` to see which bar chart has been clicked.

```
<BarChart
  width={500}
  height={500}
  layout="vertical"
  data={data}
  onClick={(data) => {
    // do your history.push based on data.activePayload[0]
    if (data && data.activePayload && data.activePayload.length > 0) {
      return history.push(`/${data.activePayload[0].x.y.id}`);
    }
  }}
>
  <XAxis type="number" />
  <YAxis dataKey="title" type="category" />
  <Bar
    dataKey="score"
    fill={Color}
    label={<CustomLabel />}
  />
</BarChart>
```

Comment: The condition `if (data.activePayload.length > 0)` will not work as data is `null` when the axis's title is clicked. Use `if (data)` instead.